# Mockito Core Matcher-GreaterThan

Tags: junit, mockito, matcher, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to upgrade the mockito version in my project.

Current version:  mockito-all [1.9.5]

Upgrade to     :  mockito-core [2.8.8]

Some of my old tests are failing with this issue

**Test:**

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.paymentTransaction.totalAmount").value(new GreaterThan<Double>(0.0D)))
```

**Failure Message:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: For JSON path $.paymentTransaction.totalAmount type of value 
Expected :class org.mockito.internal.matchers.GreaterThan
Actual   :class java.lang.Double
```

Any clue, if this is to be handled in a different way with the mockito version upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

You ended up using the wrong overload:

`public ResultMatcher value(Object expectedValue)`
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/JsonPathResultMatchers.html#value-java.lang.Object-

Instead of

`public <T> ResultMatcher value(Matcher<T> matcher)`
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/JsonPathResultMatchers.html#value-org.hamcrest.Matcher-

The reason is you used matcher from Mockito, not from Hamcrest. You need to use:
`org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan(T value)`

Also, note that there is an overload of `jsonPath` taking a Hamcrest matcher as a second argument (no need to call `value`)